# Android Exit/Enter Transition

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-transitions

I'm trying to implement an **exit transition** for my MainActivity and it does not work. If I'm trying to select a certain view it always results in a **crossfade** of both activities.

```
//Results in a Fade
getWindow().setExitTransition(new TransitionSet()); 

//Results in a Slide
getWindow().setExitTransition(new TransitionSet().addTransition(new Slide()));

//Results in a Fade
getWindow().setExitTransition(new TransitionSet().addTransition(new Slide().addTarget(view)));
```

Comment: So the problem is fading? You want to disable fading?

Comment: No, i want to slide a certain view to the bottom in this case a BottomNavigationView but it doesn't work.I tried it with different views for example a TextView and it also doesn't work.

Comment: I dont know how i fixed it. I just made a new layout file and it worked. So this is probably a bug.